# What is collaborative Intelligent filtering?

Tags: collaborative-filtering

i looked it up in the internet (ofcourse), and found nothing like it exactly, what I saw was intelligent collaborative filtering and simply collaborative filtering.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I am quite up-to-date on what people are talking about regarding collaborative filtering today (via [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org)) and I have never heard this as a special term. If you could point to your source, maybe others can shed light on what is special about this sort of CF. But as far as I can guess, the writer was just speaking about "doing CF well".